# How does an organic acid change the structure of chrysotile asbestos?

Tags: acid-base

This patent (https://patents.google.com/patent/US5041277A/en) describes how dilute acids such as lactic acid and acetic acid can change the fibrous structure of chrysotile asbestos with up to 98% efficiency. The inventor goes on to say how the end result is no more dangerous than sand, but I don't understand why. What is the new structure after it reacts with the acid?

Comment: Mmm, wording in this patent it pretty lame. Essentially, this is simple acid-base reaction, with stronger acid displacing weaker.